# extjs proper way to replace main center panel

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS, on a menu toolbar button, I am trying to remove the current panel in my center window, then recreate it with the new selection. I do not understand the proper way to do this. So far when I click the menu item, it removes whatever is currently there successfully, then it will add the new panel successfully. The problem is the 2nd time I hit the button I get the following error:

```
REGISTERING DUPLICATE COMPONENT ID 'mainportalID'.
```

I realize its telling me I already used this ID, but then what would be the correct way to remove the current panel, and replace with a new one?

Here is my view controller:

```
    selectMenuButton: function (button, e) {

    console.log('select menu button section was hit')
    console.log(button);
    console.log(e);

    var optionString = button.text;
    var myDetailsPanel = Ext.getCmp('navview');
    console.log(myDetailsPanel);

    var count = myDetailsPanel.items.items.length;
    if (count > 0) {
        myDetailsPanel.items.each(function (item, index, len) {
            myDetailsPanel.remove(item, false);
        });
    }

    myDetailsPanel.add({
        xtype: optionString
    });
}


var myStore = Ext.create('ExtApplication1.store.PositionsStore');

var gridSummary = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
store: myStore,
width: 600,
title: 'my first grid',
columns: [
    {
        text: 'AcctNum',
        dataIndex: 'AcctNum',
        width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'AcctShortCode',
        dataIndex: 'AcctShortCode',
        flex: 1
    },
    {
        text: 'Exchange',
        dataIndex: 'Exchange',
        width: 200
    }
]
});
```

This is my view

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.main.MainPortal', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

xtype: 'mainportal',

alias: 'widget.mainportal',

id: 'mainportalID',

html: 'user... this is the main portal window',

autoScroll: true,

bodyPadding: 10,

items: [
    gridSummary
]

});
```

adjusted panel

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.main.MainPortal', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    xtype: 'mainportal',

    alias: 'widget.mainportalAlias',

    reference: 'gridtextfield',

    //id: 'mainportalID',

    html: 'user... this is the main portal window',

    autoScroll: true,

    bodyPadding: 10,

    items: [
        gridSummary
    ]

});
```

adjusted view controller

```
    onComboboxSelect: function (combo, record, eOpts) {

    console.log('new listener was hit');

    //return selected Item
    var selectedValue = record.get('ClientName');
    var selectedCID = record.get('ClientID');

    //find the grid that was created
    var me = this;
    console.log(me);
    var xxx = this.lookupReference('gridtextfield');
    debugger;

    //debugger;

    var mainPortalView = Ext.getCmp('mainportalID');
    var targetGrid = mainPortalView.down('grid');

    //find the store associated with that grid
    var targetStore = targetGrid.getStore();

    //load store
    targetStore.load({
        params: {
            user: 'stephen',
            pw: 'forero',
            cid: selectedCID
        }
        //callback: function (records) {
        //    Ext.each(records, function (record) {
        //        console.log(record);
        //    });

        //    console.log(targetStore);
        //}
    });
},
```

added listeners to MainPortal.js

```
var myStore = Ext.create('ExtApplication1.store.PositionsStore');

var gridSummary = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
store: myStore,
width: 600,
title: 'my first grid',
columns: [
    {
        text: 'AcctNum',
        dataIndex: 'AcctNum',
        width: 100
    },
    {
        text: 'AcctShortCode',
        dataIndex: 'AcctShortCode',
        flex: 1
    },
    {
        text: 'Exchange',
        dataIndex: 'Exchange',
        width: 200
    }
],

listeners: {
    destroy: function () {
        debugger;
    }
}

});



Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.main.MainPortal', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

xtype: 'mainportal',

alias: 'widget.mainportalAlias',

//id: 'mainportalID',
itemId: 'mainportalID',

html: 'user... this is the main portal window',

autoScroll: true,

bodyPadding: 10,

items: [
    gridSummary
],

listeners: {
    destroy: function () {
        debugger;
    }
}
```

});

Comment: your best bet is not to use the `id` if you're chasing component reuse.  Consider a `reference` or `itemId` instead.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work... edited code above